# Windows Phone 7 Connection with a wifi-enabled micro controller

Tags: sockets, windows-phone-7, wifi, microcontroller

How can i connect a windows phone 7 device with a WiFi-enabled micro controller. Should i use socket programming?? If yes then how?? I actually want to send a text file or a text message to the micro controller using WI-FI??

Comment: Note, WiFi-enabled micro controller must be a Hot-spot, or WP7 and device should be in one network to setup p2p connection

Comment: Without knowing more about the micro-controller (like what protocols it 'speaks') nobody will be able to answer your question.  If it has an HTTP interface you may be able to use WebClient/HTTPWebRequest but it's more likely you'll need to use sockets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a bit vague. Are you trying to write a app that enables you to send a text file/message?

or are you trying to accomplish this by connecting to the microcontroller with the default connection your phone provides.

If you want to write your own app, you can do this by using a windows socket function. Have you looked into the standard code examples windows provides? They provide good examples about the basis of windows phone wifi connectivity

in example:
[Example 1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202959%28v=vs.92%29.aspx)

[Example 2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202863%28v=vs.92%29.aspx)

Edit:

You should take a look at this example. 
[Example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202858%28v=vs.92%29.aspx)
In this microsoft example, they make the game tic tac too between two windows phones. For your cause, you can read the data form file. Temporarly store it in an array. And send it over wifi. if you customize the example to fit your needs, so in steps:
Declare a socket (with the right ip adresses, ports etc)
Read file
Store in array
Send array by the wifi (using your previously declared socket)

And then on the microcontroller, you need some way to filter your data out of the incomming wifi buffer. I looked into one of my older projects where i did something like this. But i couldn't find it anymore. So i must have deleted it at some point "sorry :( " i you can work this out using the example

Comment: No not text messages but text files or rather commands that will manipulate the micro controller. For instance I want to send a command to the micro controller to alter 'n' pins. How do I do that?...

Comment: can you tell us more about the micro controller, and how you are planning to read values form the network? this might help me find you an anwser

Comment: Well i haven't bought a micro-controller yet. Ill break it down to you. Tell if i'm mad and this isn't possible. I want to use text commands send them over a micro-controller through WiFi to control some electrical appliances. I have just completed the part of taking text inputs. Now what i need to know is how i send these to the WiFi enabled micro-controller. Once i know it is possible to send commands to such and such and device i'll buy the suitable device.

Comment: Oké that makes things pretty clear. I've done the exact same thing before, but not by a windows phone. But it should be no problem accomplishing this by windows phone, because it implements the "socket" namespace. The micro controller i used was an mBed with a wifly module to enable the wifi part. So its definitly possible.. your not "mad" :P

Comment: @HammadAnwer i've update my anwser and added an extra example.